# HTML Menu : Set Selected item Icon Highlited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images.  When one is clicked, I want it to highlight that image and set the others normal.   Could this be done with jQuery toggle ?

Comment: Please post the HTML you have so far

Comment: what does your mark up look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");  //remove the highlight css class from anything that has it
  $(this).addClass("highlight"); //add the highlight css class to the image that was clicked.
});
```

Comment: You'd also need to use (something like): `$('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');` to 'set the others [to] normal.'

Comment: yeah, caught that just as you were writing the comment

Comment: Yes, that's what the first line does.